# KineticJS Stage draggable perfomance

Tags: javascript, performance, kineticjs

Good afternoon. I have a small problem with the optimization KineticJS and stage. When drag the scene on my computer, it runs smoothly. When to try a more low-end machines, it appears slowly and some king of slide-show. Here code of initialize Kinetic:

```
this.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: WF_Config.gameWindowId,
    width: $(stageContainerDOM).width(),
    height: $(stageContainerDOM).height(),
    draggable: true,
    //TODO: test on other browsers. I really not understand what it's doing :)
    dragOnTop: false,
    scale: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    }
});
this.layers = {
    //Listen for events only for ground cells
    ground: new Kinetic.Layer(),
    grid: new Kinetic.Layer({
        listening: false
    }),
    buildings: new Kinetic.Layer({
        listening: false
    }),
    tooltip: new Kinetic.Layer({
        listening: false
    })
};
```

How I can increase performance of this? Here [test site](http://ghaiklor.github.io/waroffuture/game). Click Create game and write to name and password some string and in count of players some integer. And you see this.
P.S. Thanks for help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you supply a code snippet here of your problem? I tried opening your game. I gave up after waiting 1 minute on the opening "please, wait" screen.  BTW, canvas runs much more slowly on mobile devices so your desire to optimize is a good idea.

Comment: I noticed a problem jQuery 2.0 with Opera. I can't open game in Opera too. In other browsers it's work fine. That's the problem, I do not know what part of the code can be optimized. I just set draggable in Kinetic.Stage and all. And question "How optimize this default draggable property?". Thanks.
P.S. Here [Scene.js](https://github.com/ghaiklor/waroffuture/blob/master/js/Scene.js) which realize all drawing in game.

Comment: One thing: scaling on canvas is a drain on performance.  Can you avoid scaling?

Comment: Maybe another thing: instead of composing your background with individual cell images, how about creating a static background (it's probably larger than your viewport) and then just scroll the static background in the viewport.

Comment: If I understand you right, than how I will detect clicking on cells and detect id of clicked cell? My background is different images, where work "on" method. And one more thing. If I try to cache shapes to image, than caching work only on viewport, not on all stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at caching.  You could cache the entire stage right before dragging and dropping.  This temporarily converts the entire stage into an image.  Here's a tut on caching:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-shape-caching-with-kineticjs/

Comment: I'll try. But if I will try converts shapes to image before dragging and then again draw shapes without caching...It will very slowly, I think.

Comment: I realize caching and it works fine for me. But how I will detect cells now?